# "Too many redirects". No access to Magento back end

Tags: magento-1.9

Just tried logging into Magento CE back end, and its returning a "Too many redirects occurred trying to open page" message.  Several of us using different browsers in locations are having same problem with same site.  Any ideas please?

Comment: can you see front end?

Comment: thanks...yes i can see our website as normal.

Answer (score 1):

Open your phpmyadmin from your host try once this sql command.
Run this Sql

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE core_store SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE core_store_group SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE core_website SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin'; 
UPDATE customer_group SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Now admin can able to login.
please follow this [admin page shows 404 page not found](http://tejabhagavan.blogspot.in/2015/12/after-install-magento-admin-page-shows.html)

Comment: thanks v much...i've suggested this to someone who is better than me at these things...and they are looking into it. appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: If you feel it was helpful, plz upvote on this answer

Comment: Hi...just got the other person that was helping me to do this...so its worked. Thanks very much. I've upvoted too.

Comment: Ok tnQ, All the best.